# Finding the probability of the cards

Tags: probability

From a deck of 52 cards, half of the cards were randomly removed. From the remaining cards, 3 cards are drawn randomly. What is the probability that all are king?

I considered two cases, one in which neither of the kings were removed and the other where one king was removed.
I got the answer 1/13*5*8 but the answer is 1/25*17*13

Comment: I think you can ignore the first step and just say, what is the probability of drawing 3 kings from a deck of cards.  Setting aside half the deck and then drawing doesn't affect the result.

Comment: To finish it your way, it may be necessary to consider also the cases where 3 or 4 kings were removed. Weigh each subcalculation by the probability of that many kings being removed, and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine shuffling a full deck and placing them in slots numbered 1-52.  Assume numbers 1-3 are the ones you will be drawing and numbers 27-52 are the ones that are randomly removed.

Now the problem is just, what is the probability of selecting three kings from a standard deck.  Which would be $\frac{4}{52}\times\frac{3}{51}\times\frac{2}{50}$, which I believe is the answer you had.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer. But why shouldn't setting half the cards aside affect the probability?

Comment: You could set aside all but three of the cards and it would still be the same probability. This is because it doesn't make any difference if the cards you are not consulting are in your hand or on the table.

Comment: That's what I hoped the "slot" idea might explain.  Your portioning 26 cards to be pulled out, 3 to be chosen, and 23 to remain.  It doesn't matter what order you do this, or how you present it.  The probability of those 3 slots you are interested in remains constant.